# Sequential http requests angular 4

Tags: angular

I am trying to do sequential http requests in angular 4. I have one http request which returns an Observable object as follows:

```
repos$: Observable<Repo[]>;
this.repos$ = this.candidateService.getCandidateList(); // this method performs the http request

getCandidateList(){
this.http.get<Repo[]>('https://api.github.com/user/repos', {headers});
}
```

Each of the returned Repo objects contains a field called subscribers_url, that I need to extract and perform a GET request on. Is there any way to do this? I have tried using mergeMap but it didn't seem to work.

EDIT:

```
  interface Repo {
  name: string;
  url: string;
  full_name: string;
  subscribers_url: string;
}
```

Comment: is  Repo objects array?

Comment: You need to clarify the question. For example getCandidate list return array. and then you need to go throught array and make requests

Comment: @alexKhymenko Repo is an interface that I've created. I will add the interface definition to the question now.

Comment: i mean when you make second request you need to loop throught array get object from backend add it to array?

Comment: Ideally, I want to add another field in the Repo interface called "collaborator" and I want to use the response from the second http request to assign to this field.

Comment: answered try it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could loop through the returned list of repos, and hit another call passing in the url of each repo like this:

```
repos$.subscribe({
  repo => {
     for(var i = 0; i < repo.length; i++){
         this.dynamicGetRequest(repo[i].url).subscribe({
                 res=>console.log(res);
             })
     }
   }
});


dynamicGetRequest(url) {
   this.http.get<any>(url, {headers});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
 repos$: Observable<Repo[]>;
this.repos$ = this.candidateService.getCandidateList()
.switchMap((list: Repo[]) => {
  let requests = list.map((i) => {
     return this.secondRequest(i)
   })
  return Observalbe.forkJoin(requests).map((dataList)=>{
     return dataList.map((data, index) => {
         return {
              ...list[index], 
              collaborator: data
            }
      })
    })
})
 getCandidateList(){
this.http.get<Repo[]>('https://api.github.com/user/repos', {headers});
}
```